# Given html decoded values in the DB how to output as encoded in an Input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, knockout.js

In my database I have:

```
ListItem.title = Hello &amp; Goodbye3
```

Then in my view I have:

```
ko.mapping.updateFromJS(List.list_items_open, <%= raw @list.list_items.where(:completed => false).to_json(:only => [:id, :title, :completed, :position]) %> );

<ol data-bind='template: { name: "list_item_template", foreach: List.list_items_open}'></ol>

<script type="text/html" id="list_item_template">
  <li class="listItem">
     <input class="list_item_title" maxlength="250" name="list_item[title]" type="text" data-bind="value: title>
  </li>
</script>
```

Problem here is that the value in the input is being rendered as:

```
Hello &amp; Goodbye3
```

And not:

```
Hello & Goodbye3
```

Any ideas on how I should be handling this? Were I should be encoding as raw? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the content in the database, I would say don't encode text in the database. You should store your text as "Hello & Goodbye3".

See [Should we HTML-encode special characters before storing them in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598802/should-we-html-encode-special-characters-before-storing-them-in-the-database) for more discussion.

Comment: I agree unless the Title column is actually meant to be raw html (like you could add tags, ie. `Hello <strong>Goodbye</strong>` is a valid value).  If its only meant to be text though, definitely don't pre-encode it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control over the content in the database you could use a dependentObservable which deals with the encoding and decoding:

```
<p data-bind="text:name"></p>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: nameConverted "></input>

var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable('Hello &amp; Goodbye3')
};

viewModel.nameConverted = ko.dependentObservable({
    read: function() {
        return htmlDecode(this.name());
    },
    write: function(value) {
        this.name(htmlEncode(value));
    },
    owner: viewModel
});

function htmlEncode(value){ 
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
} 

function htmlDecode(value){ 
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text(); 
} 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/k8jYN/ for a working example.